# Sitecore custom api routing is not working

Tags: sitecore-api, upgrade, webapi, routing, api

We have a multi-site environment.

In one of the module, we are calling the same `controller/action` from all the sites. Perhaps, the same Javascript file which calls this `controller/action`  is included in all the sites. But, I'm able to get the response from `Site1` but, `Site2` is redirecting the request to `404`.

```
http://site1/api/mic/MyController/myaction -- Is working

http://site2/api/mic/MyController/myaction -- Is not working
```

Recently we have `upgraded from Sitecore 8.0.4 to Sitecore 9.0.2`, In `Sitecore 8 instance both are working`.

Just to debug the issue,

- I had deleted the `Site.Config for`Site2` and tested, it is able to get the proper response. Not sure what's happening here. Attached the site config below.
  [image]
- Also noticed that from `site2` I'm not able to hit any of the controller/action.

I suspect that, Api routing is not working. When we include Site2's site.config, Sitecore routing is taking place, not the mvc routing.

Your help and prompt response are appreciated.

**UPDATE 1 :**
I had noticed that, in Site definition, when the start item is pointing to Site2's home item, i'm getting error. It works with any other item in the content tree. Is there any problem with Sitecore item? or did i missed any configuration?

**UPDATE 2 :**

I noticed that, under Site2 Sitecore node, we have wild card items. Something like this

```
StartItem/*/*
```

This is matching `http://site2/api/mic/MyController/myaction` request.

Now I'm sure that, when we call the api it is matching the Sitecore Content tree items and then it is redirecting to 404 page.

Now the question is how to tell Sitecore to take mvc routing as routing for this request?

Answer (score 2):

It needs to create custom routing for calling a controller action method for multisite. Steps are as below:

**Step 1)** Add App_start folder in the **Foundation Layer** Project. Add a class file in this folder e.g. RegisterWebApiRoutes.cs, use the below code in this class file.

```
public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("API", "api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "controllerName", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "dllName.Controllers" } //e.g. Sitecore.Foundation.Accounts.Controllers
            );
        }
```

**Step 2)** created the config file of that layer, register the routing e.g. `Sitecore.Foundation.Accounts.config` use below  code for register routing:

```
 <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Accounts.App_Start.RegisterWebApiRoutes,Sitecore.Foundation.Accounts" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>  </sitecore>
```

I hope it will work for you because it worked for me.

Comment: Its already there in common solution. Also, i have added the above config for this site aswell. Not working. As i told, Sitecore 8 instance working without any issues.

Comment: Please check the Sitecore.Mvc.dll version for sitecore 9.0.2.

Comment: Its Version  2.2.0.206 and its Sitecore 9.0.2/